# How to remove the padding of a button with nested label with JavaFX CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

As you can see a label ("a123") is nested within a button. Since the label has a background color, I would like it to engulf the whole height and left side of the button. Can you suggest the right way to do it?

Current situation:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

My solution:

```
<Button fx:id="rootContainer" alignment="TOP_LEFT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="190.0" stylesheets="@../../../commons/util/resources/myCSS.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.features.dashboard.userorder.UserOrderPresenter">
    <graphic>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
            <children>
                  <Label fx:id="labelTableName" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" focusTraversable="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="70.0" styleClass="label-table-number" text="a123" textFill="WHITE">
                      <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="-8.0" left="-15.0" top="-8.0" />
                      </HBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

Comment: please give code that what have you done so we can help you.

Comment: Have you tried `rootContainer.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px");`?

Comment: @ankitapatel Thanks buddy! Sedrick helped with his code. Once again thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the edit! I can finally see the images embedded!

Comment: I upvoted your question, so for your next question, you should be able to [embed images yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques) if you need to :-)

Comment: @jewelsea Awesome! Thanks a ton for your upvote! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try negative margins.

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0">
         <graphic>
            <HBox>
               <children>
                  <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: black; -fx-text-fill: white;" text="Label">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="-3.0" left="-7.0" right="-3.0" top="-3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </graphic>
      </Button>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sedrick! That was exactly what I was looking for.